# Выборка jQuery. Выбор элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть select в котором есть option. Как сделать добавление стилей тому option в котором только одна точка?

```
<select>
    <option>.1</option>
    <option>..2</option>
    <option>..3</option>
    <option>.2</option>
    <option>..1</option>
    <option>..2</option>
</select>
```

Я написал условия, но у меня косяк

```
if($("option").text().indexOf('.') > 0 ){
    $("option").css("background-color", "red");
}
else {
    $("option").css("background-color", "green");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать без js, правда придется добавить `value` с таким же значением

```css
select option[value^="."] {
    background-color: red;
}
select option[value^=".."] {
    background-color: initial;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value=".1">.1</option>
    <option value="..2">..2</option>
    <option value="..3">..3</option>
    <option value=".2">.2</option>
    <option value="..1">..1</option>
    <option value="..2">..2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: $( "option:contains('. ')" ).css( "background-color", "red" ); Я сделал вот так вот

Comment: НО, как сделать для option конкретно с одной точкой?

Comment: @АлександрТкаченко, обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Цвет зависит от второго символа в тексте у option(`textContent[1] === '.'`)
Но этот скрипт учитывает что всегда идет две точки или точка.

```js
const options = document.querySelector('select').options

;[...options].forEach(i => 
  i.style['background-color'] = (i.textContent[1] === '.' ? 'red' : 'green')
)
```

```html
<select>
  <option>.1</option>
  <option>..2</option>
  <option>..3</option>
  <option>.2</option>
  <option>..1</option>
  <option>..2</option>
  <!-- если такого не будет в селекте -->
  <option>o.text</option>
  <option>text</option>
</select>
```

Более надежный но длиннее код. Сравнивает честь строки через slice

```js
const options = document.querySelector('select').options

;[...options].forEach(i => {
  let color
  if (i.textContent.slice(0, 2) === '..')
    color = 'red'
  else if (i.textContent.slice(0, 1) === '.')
   color = 'green'
   
  i.style['background-color'] = color
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option>.1</option>
  <option>..2</option>
  <option>..3</option>
  <option>.2</option>
  <option>..1</option>
  <option>..2</option>
  <option>o.text</option>
  <option>text</option>
</select>
```